# New library on sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Hi I want to create a library or a site.. or anything pretty much under one site. 
Which can have the capacity to write a text and also upload a document in that. 
I donot want t discussion board, because I donot want people to reply on that.

So basically a discussion board sort of layout but without replies and all..! How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible page I've worked with is a web parts page. You can drop any web part on there that will get you 80% of what you want. There is a web part to display/interact with lists (document library in your case), and a blank html web part will allow you to display any text.
Web parts can be in different positions on the page to mimic a discussion board layout.

It's unclear to me what you want other than to prevent users from writing in their own messages. More context of what you are trying to achiever would help get a more specific answer.